Icons and UI Not Displaying in WiX Bootstrap Bundled Application After Upgrading to WiX v5
After upgrading my WiX project from WiX v3.11 to WiX v5, the following problems have arisen:

The main window of the bootstrapper application displays only the title bar, with the rest of the window remaining white.
Icons and other UI elements (buttons, text, images) that were previously visible are no longer displayed.

I tried the below things:

Simplified Theme File: I have attempted to create a minimal theme.xml file to isolate the problem, but the issue persists.
Verbose Logging: Enabled verbose logging to gather more details, but the logs have not provided sufficient information to resolve the issue.
Predefined Theme: Tested with predefined themes provided by WiX to determine if the issue was specific to the custom theme, but the problem continues to occur.
Correct Paths: Verified that all paths to theme files and resources are correctly specified and accessible.

Please find below the simplified code of Theme.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/theme">
    <Font Id="WixUI_Font_Title" Name="Arial" Size="14" Height="20" Bold="yes" />
    <Font Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" Name="Arial" Size="10" Height="13" />
    <Window Id="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="400" Background="white" Title="[ProductName] Setup" FontId="WixUI_Font_Normal" Caption="TestAPP">
        <Text Id="Title" X="10" Y="10" Width="480" Height="30" FontId="WixUI_Font_Title" Caption="Welcome to the [ProductName] setup wizard" />
    <Button Id="NextButton" X="400" Y="350" Width="80" Height="30" Text="Next" />
    <Button Id="CancelButton" X="310" Y="350" Width="80" Height="30" Text="Cancel" />
    </Window>
</Theme>

Despite these efforts, the application window remains mostly white with only the title bar visible.

That is a known issue: #8104 - Icon no longer displayed in the Burn bundle window title and Windows taskbar after upgrading to WiX 5.0.0.

Thanks Rob for your prompt reply. After downgrading Wix V5 to Wix 4.0.5 now Icon is appearing but the UI is not getting displayed the entire window is white. Please help.

That's a different question. If this answered your question please accept it (so it falls off my query of unanswered questions) and open a new question with details about the new issue you're seeing.
